# Access to static files in MVC 3 in an Azure web role on the Visual Studio Development Webserver

Tags: windows-7

I'm having issues serving out static (image) files from an Azure + MVC 3 project when running in the dev web server. I have forms authentication running on the site, and any requests for images are met with a login redirect.

I have been able to make access possible by making my images folder an application (via iis) and explicitly setting my windows user to have access to the images folder, though this only works for a debugging session, and clearly isn't a real solution.

There are a couple of problems it *isn't*:

- Static file requests being picked up by mapped routes
- Folder permissions not allowing access to the NETWORK SERVICE account
- Rules in web.config requiring authorization for the folder

Currently the images reside in ~/Images/... though I have also had them in ~/Content/... which is where the main css resides. Said css always serves out without any issues.

Notably the images are not served even if you do log in.

I realise that it may be better to store these images in a blob, particularly in the development phase, and for source control, it seems easier to carry these few static resources in a project folder.

**EDIT** - Question was incorrect. Actually just an issue with some files being encrypted on my hd and others not, causing odd results.

Comment: Stupid question, are those images marked as content? What error are you getting? 404? 401?

Comment: @vtortola - If I switch of forms auth I get a 401.3. If I override and set the context to run as my windows identity it serves fine. As for being marked as content, that's not a stupid question at all! I'm not in front of the solution at present but when I am I will be double checking that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out windows was encrypting all of the files in these directories (not standard behaviour for my configuration, but was happening here for one reason or another). I had a couple of images that weren't encrypted (including the styles.css) but most of the images were. That meant that images wouldn't serve without my credentials against them...

So nothing to do with mvc / azure / cassini!

Comment: How could you tell that they were encrypted? I have a similar issue where static content returns a 401 for me, but I am not prompted for credentials?? And I can navigate to the images and display them in the browser, really weird...

Comment: In windows 7 natively encrypted files are shown in green (I didn't know this at the time). Probably when you are viewing the files in the browser the browser's credential context allows access.

Comment: I had this exact same issue.  Any idea what causes Windows to select certain images for encryption?

Comment: @PinnyM I think it was to do with where I was copying them from. I think I had a folder (or maybe a USB key) which had Windows encryption switched on, and when I copied files from there Windows maintained the encrypted state.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is some config issue and is not related to Azure itself.

It is probably worth trying similar questions/answers like:
[My ASP.NET MVC2 application with Forms Authentication is blocking access even to Images, Styles and Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722399/my-asp-net-mvc2-application-with-forms-authentication-is-blocking-access-even-to)

Also, if you create a new project then do you see the same effect?

- If no, then compare the web.config type settings one by one - the difference will be there.
- If yes, then it seems like the problem is somehow at the web server/machine level (maybe something to do with anon or windows authentication in web.config and/or app.config)

Comment: I agree - and these are the issues I've tried looking into. But I can have an image and css side by side in the "Content" directory and the css will serve fine, the .gif will not. Anonymous access is allowed throughout except for controller based [Authorize] attributes, and I've explicitly set allow all users on Content and Images directories in the web config.

Additionally the reason Azure is tagged is because I can set up the mvc site on it's own, in IIS, with no changes to the web.config and the images are served out fine.